# On hover function not working in multiple elements with the same id

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

My idea is that when you hover over an image, a black 0.9 opacity div appears in front, showing some information. It is indeed working but only with the first element, then it doesn't at all. I'm using the same `id`'s and classes because the system I am using creates a for each statement and repeats the syntax with different contents. I can't seem to make it work, please help!

here's the code on fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/9dzU6/

Thank you in advance! Have a nice day! :)

Comment: "I'm using the same id's" - well there's your problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how ids work. They should be unique. If you want multiple, you should use a class and the select ".myClass".

[Here is the fiddle fixed](http://jsfiddle.net/nGLXR/2/)
I think the CSS should be corrected, but you can still see the JS works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

IDs should be unique. If you want to assign it to multiple items, use it as a class instead. That means, you may try;

`$('.distinguished')` instead of `$('#distinguished')` after assigning class.